# Can this be undone to make a knotless loop?

Tags: no-computers, topology

Can this be undone to make a knotless loop?

[image]

Comment: If you had a length of nylon rope, you could tie these knots in it and then melt the ends together with a flame to reproduce the figure in the real world to try to solve it manually.

Comment: ...probably knot...

Comment: How should one answer this question? Unless there is some 'tricky' answer involved, it could be hard to draw this out

Comment: I was waiting for the knot-sounds-like-not joke.

Comment: I suggest you put a [tag:no-computers] tag on this puzzle, since another site on StackExchange has a program derived from a research paper that can solve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Answer:**

> It cannot.

**Explanation:**

In general, proving a knot is not the trivial knot is a very nontrivial task (no more knot/not puns, I promise!). The general strategy is to find some property of the knot that is preserved by continuous deformations, and show that the trivial knot does not have this property. Such properties are called knot invariants.

In this case one property that works is [tricolorability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricolorability). A knot is tricolorable if you can color the strands in its diagram so that (a) the three strands at every crossing are either all the same or all different, and (b) at least two colors are used. The fact that this is a knot invariant follows from the fact that any continuous transformation of a knot corresponds to a sequence of local ["Reidemeister moves"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reidemeister_move) on its diagram, and that these moves do not affect tricolorability (which can be checked directly for each of the three moves).

The below image shows that the given knot is tricolorable. However, the usual diagram of a trivial knot is one with a singe strand and no crossings, and no coloring can satisfy (b).

[image]

Comment: +1 basically what I just spent the last 20 minutes reading haha

Comment: I would say that this answer ties up all the loose ends, but the question didn't have any.

Comment: Oh...my...god...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a neat different explanation.

> Imagine you put a sheath around the string. In the section at the top of the picture, the sheath follows the string around the loop to become similarly tangled up (I won't say knotted, as that is what we're trying to prove). However, around the rest of the string, let the sheath become a bit wider to engulf the whole lot without following the entanglements. What you are left with is a sheath in the shape of a loop that has a single trefoil knot in it. This is the simplest known knot.
>
> If there were any way of untangling the original string, you would be able to apply it to the sheathed string, allowing the sheath to stretch in whatever way is necessary without breaking it. This would mean that the trefoil knot could be untangled as well, which we know is not possible.
>
> This shows that it does not matter what happens in the rest of the string - if it has one isolated trefoil in it, it is knotted.